# How to apply gravity to the items in Linear Layout, whose orientation is Horizontal?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I have a Parent linear layout, whose orientation is `vertical`, under this i have another layout whose orientation is `vertical`, and it has a child layout whose orientation is `Horizontal`.

This layout has  2 `Image Views`. , I want to apply gravity to these Image `views`.1 With `left-gravity`, and 1 with `right-gravity`.

When i apply gravity to this layout it does not make any effect, but if i remove the last `horizontal` layout it perfectly works, but shows 1 image  up and 1 down.

This is my code, Kindly guide me

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b9000000"
    android:id="@+id/ll_black_overlay"
    >

   //There are 2 More layouts, whith weights 20 and 50

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        >

        // Layout for displaying text messages Vertically

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text View 1 , "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text View 002 , "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                />


 </LinearLayout>

  // --Problem area Layout for displaying Images side by side,
      1 image at left corner, 1 at right corner, if i remove Linear layout,
      gravity works, but id is not working with Linear Layout 

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_left"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_right"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

it will display both images two equal with in screen
if you want both images at corner add another textview at between two images with layout_weight

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_black_overlay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#b9000000"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text View 1 , "
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text View 002 , "
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_right" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_left"/>
```

Comment: Surely this code will work for you. I will tested it.

Comment: Add </RelativeLayout> in the end of the code. Don't forgot to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use the below layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_black_overlay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#b9000000"
android:orientation="vertical">

//There are 2 More layouts, whith weights 20 and 50

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="70dp"
    android:paddingRight="70dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    // Layout for displaying text messages Vertically

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text View 1 , "
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text View 002 , "
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>

    // --Problem area Layout for displaying Images side by side,
    1 image at left corner, 1 at right corner, if i remove Linear layout,
    gravity works, but id is not working with Linear Layout

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just add LinearLayout with weight 1 in between ImageViews.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_tour_arrow_right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```